# Merging `figures` and `diagrams`?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We currently have two tags which apparently address the same object --- `figures` and `diagrams`. While there's a semantic difference between the two (in content/representation), it's all the same for LaTeX.

I suggest we use `figures` for questions related to external stand-alone files (e.g. PNG, PDF, EPS) that you cannot edit within LaTeX, and to use `diagrams` for those that are produced by e.g. `tikz`, `pgf`, `psticks`, or whatever.

Alternatively, we can just use `diagrams` tag as a synonym for `figures`.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Commonly, questions regarding figures deal with including, floating, captioning, referring, sizing and positioning and the like, typically involved packages are float and graphicx. However, if questions concern diagrams I believe it's mainly dealing with producing them. Until now, all questions [tagged with 'diagrams'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) are about typesetting and drawing, without mentioning the word 'figure', typical packages are TikZ and PSTricks, like you said.

If I'd like to create a diagram, perhaps not sure which package I should use, I would be glad to have a `[diagrams]` tag to browse such questions. They don't get lost among questions concerning prefabricated figures.

Finally, the tags [`[figures]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) and [`[diagrams]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) are not even related, as I can see on the side bar.

So I believe we should not merge those tags.

Answer (score 4):

I was satisfied with Stefan's answer, but I think we should revisit this issue, as there are several somewhat related tags that should be disambiguated.

My proposal is to keep

- [`[diagrams]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) for  typesetting/drawing typically with e.g. TikZ or other packages. The tag [`[picture]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture) (which should anyway be `[pictures]`) should be added as a synonym.
- [`[graphics]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) for external files (e.g. PNG, JPEG, etc.) inserted in documents. The tag [`[images]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) should be made a synonym. (If you like it [vote for it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/graphics/synonyms))
- [`[figures]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) for questions about the environment used to include a captioned diagram or graphic in a document.

Comment: You didn't list EPS or PDF with `graphics`... and the etc. could just be more raster formats!